# Move an app build from unity3d engine to xamarin and update to google console

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, xamarin, google-console-developer

I want to change my app made from unity to xamarin in the future.

Is it possible to upload it to playstore ? , i mean is it possible for google console to update a different platform builder from unity to xamarin ?

I mean since i have you a same keystore that unity provided.

Because making an app using xamarin will be more confortable rather than unity, since unity is a game engine and xamarin is an cross platform apps engine..

I want to use xamarin because it use c# language too same with unity..

So it is more suitable and easy to move all code from unity to c# xamarin..

Could anyone explain this for me ?

Thank you

Comment: Use the same signing key and increment the `versionCode` on the app/apk. Google console knows nothing about "how" the app is being constructed, just that the apk (or the app bundle) is valid.

Comment: @SushiHangover I didnt use signing key from google console, i have skip that part. But i just use the keystore made from unity. Did you mean the signing key is a keystore ?

Comment: Yes, the keystore contains your app (or upload) signing key

Comment: Okay than is it clear now. Later i will move all to xamarin. Could you update the answer ? I will tick it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which language or tool you built your App with does not matter at all. You will need to ensure that the following things are met to not have Google Play store think it is a new App:

- package name must be the same as the package name of the App you are replacing. Same casing also.
- you must use the *same* keystore as the App you are replacing was signed with
- as with any other update of an App, the versionCode in the manifest must be incremented - higher than the previous version of the App

That is basically it.